# "x" overwrites clipboard, I am not able to finish the copy-pase action

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I decided that I have to get rid of a couple of annoying things which decrease my productivity in Vim. I know they must have a simple solution.

So, my first question:

If I copy a word in clipboard using `yw` for example, and I want to copy this word to some other spot (or, very often, more spots), but meanwhile I have to delete something and I use `x` or `dw`, the clipboard is overwritten, and I am not able to finish the task I intended. I could enter the insert mode and use `delete` key but that is of course too much work. How do you behave in this situation and what strategy do you use?

Answer (score 5):

For the case of yanking one thing, deleting others, then pasting the yanked text instead of deleted text, I use the last-yanked register.

from `:help "0`:

> Vim fills these registers with text from yank and delete commands.
>      Numbered register 0 contains the text from the most recent yank command,
>   unless the command specified another register with ["x].
>      Numbered register 1 contains the text deleted by the most recent delete or
>   change command, unless the command specified another register or the text is
>   less than one line (the small delete register is used then).  An exception is
>   made for the delete operator with these movement commands: %, (, ), `,
>   /, ?, n, N, { and }.  Register "1 is always used then (this is Vi
>   compatible).

So, after <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> and then some <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> (or whatever), I can paste the yanked text with <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

For more complicated tasks (deleting multiple things and pasting the different multiple things) I either anticipate ahead of time and use named registers (e.g. <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>), or check the contents of the numbered registers after the deletions to see which ones have what I want to paste, using `:registers`, which might show something like

```
"0   char *^J
"1   ^I^I^Iint utf8flag = 1;^J
"2   ^Istruct window^I^I*w^J
```

If I want the struct window line, I'd then do <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>